# Android BottomNavigationView element's icons are greyed out

Tags: android

I was trying like in another answers to use res > new > Batch Drawable Import but it still does not work. How to solve that?

It looks like this:

[image]

My main_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/browser_actions_text_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_stage_zero"
        android:icon="@mipmap/zero"
        android:title="Stage 0" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_stage_one"
        android:icon="@mipmap/zero"
        android:title="Stage 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_stage_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/two"
        android:title="Stage 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_stage_three"
        android:icon="@drawable/three"
        android:title="Stage 3" />
</menu>
```

Comment: try to restart with cache

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using png format icons for the bottom nav try add the line

```
bottom_nav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

In your class place this will remove the default android behaviour of applying gray background over the icons to denote disable mode.